# How to access typescript variable in scss?(Typescript/scss)

Tags: typescript, sass

How can I access typescript variable in scss. I attached the code. I will appreciate any help.

```html
#someselector {
  @include somemixin($someargument: $valuefromtypescript);
  background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. TypeScript variables are evaluated during runtime. SCSS compiles to CSS during compile time.

The only thing that you can do is use your TypeScript variables and append classes to your DOM depending on the variable value. But that is a completely different approach.